# Exactly one nontrivial proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: Determine all the finite groups that have exactly one nontrivial proper subgroup.

MY attempt is that the order of group G has to be a positive nonprime integer n which has only one divisor since any divisor a of n will form a proper subgroup of order a. Since 4 is the only nonprime number that has only 1 divisor which is 2, All groups of order 4 has only 1 nontrivial proper subgroups (Z4 and D4)

Comment: $D_4$ is the Klein $4$-group, which has three non-trivial proper subgroups.

Comment: What about $9$?

Comment: Or 25? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Your claim that any divisor of $n$ gives you a subgroup of that order is false: for example, $A_4$ has order $12$ but no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: Hint: Pick an element outside your unique proper subgroup, and check the subgroup it generates...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154666/8581

Answer (score 10):

Let $H$ be the only non-trivial proper subgroup of the finite group $G$. Since $H$ is proper, there must exist an $x \notin H$. Now consider the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ of $G$. This subgroup cannot be equal to $H$, nor is it trivial, hence $\langle x\rangle = G$, that is $G$ is *cyclic*, say of order $n$. The number of subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ equals the number of divisors of $n$. So $n$ must have three divisors. This can only be the case if $n$ is the square of a *prime* number. So, $G \cong C_{p^2}$.

Answer (score 5):

You began reasonably, but then you went off the track. First, $D_4$ won’t work: it’s the Klein $4$-group, $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$, which has three non-trivial proper subgroups, one generated by each of the non-identity elements.

Secondly, the fact that some integer $n$ divides the order of $G$ does not ensure that $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$, as noted in the comments. You do, however, have the first [Sylow theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) available. (**Note:** This replaces the nonsense that I wrote originally.)

Finally, $4$ isn’t the only non-prime with only one non-trivial divisor: for each prime $p$, $p^2$ is such a number. You want at least the groups $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$, or in your notation $\Bbb Z_{p^2}$, for all primes $p$. Can you identify exactly what the non-trivial proper subgroup is in each of these groups?

Comment: @anon: Yes, I realized almost immediately that I’d written an idiocy. You apparently caught it just about when I did.

Answer (score 1):

Hints/questions to consider: Have you done Sylow's theorem? How many Sylow subgroups can your group have? Show that your group must be cyclic- (hint for this: if not, all its element are in the unique proper subgroup). How many subgroups does a cyclic group of order $p^{n}$ have, when $p$ is prime and $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Why do we need Sylow's to think about cyclic groups?

Comment: We don't, but *a priori* such a finite group could be anything. We use Sylow's theorem to exclude the non-cyclic groups from consideration.

Comment: @anon: it's a question of in what sequence you do things: you could indeed first prove the group cyclic, then conclude it must have prime power order without explicitly making use of Sylow's theorem.

Comment: @kahen As Geoff hints at, a very simple argument shows the group must be cyclic - by only considering cyclic subgroups. I feel Sylow is too high-powered for this exercise; in fact I suspect this is an exercise from *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*'s chapter on cyclic groups, which is *way* before Sylow tech is even touchable. [Edit: Yes, it is exercise 34 in ch 1-4 supplementary exercises.]

Comment: @anon: I think it is probably the case that almost anyone who HAD done Sylow would think of using it. I asked Johnny whether he had done Sylow's theorem, because the problem might be easier with Sylow than without, but it certainly can be done without.